# I am struggling to draw chemical structure using chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I am struggling to draw chemical structure using chemfig[image: Linseed oil]

thank you.

Comment: Can you share what you have attempted so far?

Comment: You can get help from http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf p.35. It's a good tutorial for `chemfig`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{HC
  (-[2,2,2,2]H_2|C-O-[1](=[2,.75]O)-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]=-[-1]-[1]=-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1])
  (-[6,1.25,2,2]H_2|C-O-[-1](=[6,.75]O)-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]=-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1])
  -O-[1](=[2,.75]O)-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]=-[-1]-[1]=-[-1]-[1]=-[-1]-[1]}

\chemfig{HC
  (-[2,2,2,2]H_2|C-O-[1](=[2,.75]O)-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1](-[:60]O-[:-60])--[-1]-[1](-[:60]O-[:-60])--[-1]-[1]-[-1](-[:-60]O-[:60])--[1])
  (-[6,2,2,2]H_2|C-O-[1](=[2,.75]O)-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1](-[:60]O-[:-60])--[-1]-[1]-[-1](-[:-60]O-[:60])--[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1])
  -O-[1](=[2,.75]O)-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1](-[:60]O-[:-60])--[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]